# I want to transform an R dataframe into a dataframe with a column of list

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr, adjacency-matrix, jsonlite

Ok, I have a two column data.frame with a variable number of `child` to a `head`. (other 2 columns are reference)

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
                        head          child UID     logic
                    1  01001         01001   1     FALSE
                    2  01001         01021   2      TRUE
                    3  01001         01047   3      TRUE
                    4  01001         01051   4      TRUE
                    5  01001         01085   5      TRUE
                    6  01001         01101   6      TRUE
                    7  01003         01003   7     FALSE
                    8  01003         01025   8      TRUE
                    9  01003         01053   9      TRUE
                    10 01003         01097  10      TRUE
                    11 01003         01099  11      TRUE
                    12 01003         01129  12      TRUE
                    13 01003         12033  13      TRUE
                    14 01005         01005  14     FALSE
                    15 01005         01011  15      TRUE
                    16 01005         01045  16      TRUE
                    17 01005         01067  17      TRUE
                    18 01005         01109  18      TRUE
                    19 01005         01113  19      TRUE
                    20 01005         13061  20      TRUE
                    21 01005         13239  21      TRUE
                    22 01005         13259  22      TRUE")
```

I would like to have only three rows for the unique `head` and a list for the `child`.

If you have a suggestion of a better way to do this, I am open to it.

The other columns `UID` and `logic` I have added for reference, but they can be dropped.

In my attempts, I have tried to convert to a graph with an edgelist, then to JSON.

```
# make graph ##########
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(jsonlite)
gdat <- select(dat, head, child)
mdat <- as.matrix(gdat)
edge_dat <- graph_from_edgelist(mdat)
plot.igraph(edge_dat)
jdat <- toJSON(mdat, matrix = "rowmajor")
```

Desired output:

```
head   child1   child2   child3   child4   child5   child6   child7
01001  01001    01021    01047    01051    01085    01101    NA
01003  01003    01025    01053    ... and so on
01005  01005    01011    ... and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want ?

```
setDT(dat)

dat_child <- dat[(logic)]
dat_child[,.(list(unique(child))), by = "head"]

dat_child
   head                                      V1
1: 1001                1021,1047,1051,1085,1101
2: 1003      1025, 1053, 1097, 1099, 1129,12033
3: 1005  1011, 1045, 1067, 1109, 1113,13061,...
```

Comment: Yes, I think so... Do you recommend any other best way to store data like this?

Comment: You have many options, depending on how you want to handle them later. You can use list columns as you proposed, standard lists (use `split(dat_child, by = "head")` instead), nested data (either nested `data.table` or nested `tibble`). This is really what you will do later that will determine the most appropriate structure